# How to plot a function for big range of values?

Tags: pgfplots

I use Maple to plot the funtion `f(x) = x*(x-6)*(x-12)*(x-20)`, where `x = -.8 .. 21`.

[image]

I tried to draw it by `pgfplots`, but I can not get the result.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$}, 
    },
    framed/.style={axis background/.style ={draw=black}},
}

% arrow style
\tikzset{>=stealth}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            f(\x)=\x*(\x-6)*(\x-12)*(\x-20);
                }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        framed, grid=both,
        axis equal,
            axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        axis line style = very thick,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=20,
    yticklabels={},
    width=22 cm,
    height=2850cm, xticklabels={}, 
        samples=500,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, very thick,domain=-1:21, smooth]{f(x)};
                    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

How can I draw it?

Comment: The function is not the real problem. The main issue is `height=2850cm,`. How high should the plot really be?

Comment: @marmot Is there a way to draw? The height=2850cm, I tried a any number. You can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a plot that looks IMHO very decent if you drop `axis equal,ymin=-1.5, ymax=20,` and the enormous dimensions. `axis equal` says that the units in `x` and `y` directions should coincide, but you know from your Maple plot that in the specified domain the plot varies by roughly 5000 in `y` direction, so there is no way to reconcile this with a domain of only 21 units in `x` direction. Of course, if you cut the plot by saying `ymin=-1.5, ymax=20,` you will cut away pretty much everything. However, if you drop all this you get

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$}, 
    },
    framed/.style={axis background/.style ={draw=black}},
}

% arrow style
\tikzset{>=stealth}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={f(\x)=\x*(\x-6)*(\x-12)*(\x-20);%
                }
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        framed, grid=both,
        %axis equal,
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        axis line style = very thick,enlarge y limits=0.05,
        %ymin=-1.5, ymax=20,
    yticklabels={},
    width=12cm,
    %height=0.4*28.50cm, 
    xticklabels={}, 
        samples=101,
        ]
        \addplot[blue, very thick,domain=-1:21, smooth]{f(x)};
       \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which looks very much like the Maple plot.

Comment: the graph lost alittle at the bottom.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 better now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.